# TPL task/thread mangement

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have some 'clients' (in an abstract sense), for each client there are hundreds of jobs/tasks to be done periodically. The jobs are basically network based API calls and database operations. So let's say the jobs should be done every K minutes for each client (after last jobs has finished for this client). K is also dependent on the client (some need higher frequency). If the jobs take too long (time also dependent on the client), they need to be stopped and restarted.

Right now a timer is created (for each client) spawning some number of threads (T) (for each client) (number of threads is client-dependent). The threads go over client's jobs. If they take too long, they are aborted. It's ugly. After the client's work is finished, the timer is restarted.

One important thing is that there is a practical limit for the degree of parallelism for some clients (the number T takes care of that now). Going over some number of threads slows the external systems down.

How could I implement this using TPL?

If I just create `Tasks` for all clients and do some straightforward things like `Parallel.Foreach` I do not have control over the number of concurrent jobs **per client**.

I could convert my threads to tasks and do a `Parallel.Foreach` (or other mechanism like `Task.WhenAll`) for each client separately, in it's own timer.

Would that be fine?

Comment: It sounds like you want to schedule a set of jobs - have you considered using a scheduler like Quartz.net, which will give you the scheduling you are after with control over the max degree of parallelism?

Comment: I didn't know they exist, I'll check it out. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, thought that might be the case - it's definitely what you are looking for. There are various out there, but Quartz is probably the most flexible, hence why I suggested it, but it does have a learning curve - do a sample project first. Hangfire.Net is pretty easy to use, but I'm not sure how well it handles max-degrees of parallelism, which seems important to you (although you could build that into your jobs of course), and also it has only 1 minute resolution for it's scheduler, which might be a problem for you?